# Detect intent in prompt choice

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I use the Node Botframework Sdk, and the user have to fill out a questionnaire.

This questionnaire have three questions with the same answer "yes", "no", "maybe".

But if the user answer is "yep" or "yes of course" or "always" that can match "yes" (affirmative answer)

If the user answer is "sometimes" or "it depends" or "rarely" that can match "maybe"(nuance answer)

In the future, we must be able to predict new answer not expected at the begining (add easily new answer).

Unfortunately Prompts.choice() don't permit to bind a choice to a intent.

So Two solutions :

- Use Prompts.choice() synonyms
- Use Prompts.text() and create 3 differents intents (affirmative, nuance, negative) and pass the answer to luis. On the luis response save the good answer (yes | no | maybe)

Which one is the best solution ? Other solution exist ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the way to go here is using the synonyms of the Prompts.choice; however an alternative you can also explore is overriding some of the behaviors of the Prompts.choice to also call LUIS before parsing the response and returning if it's valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use buttons to get user entry using buttons ? However you can type this code in ResumeAfterAsync function

```
var r = await result;
if(r.ToLower.Contains("yes") || r.ToLower.Contains("yea" || .....)
{
}
```

but I think using buttons is a better way